# Qt 5 drawing translate(), rotate(), font fill issues

Tags: c++17, qt5

I'm writing my first Qt 5 application... This uses a third-party map library ([QGeoView](https://github.com/AmonRaNet/QGeoView)).

I need to draw an object (something like a stylized airplane) over this map. Following the library coding guidelines, I derived from the base class `QGVDrawItem` my `QGVAirplane`.

The airplane class contains heading and position values: such values must be used to *draw* the airplane on the map (of course in the correct position and with correct heading). The library requires `QGVDrawItem` derivatives to override three base class methods:

```
QPainterPath projShape() const;
void projPaint(QPainter* painter);
void onProjection(QGVMap* geoMap)
```

The first method is used to achieve the area of the map that needs to be updated. The second is the method responsible to draw the object on the map. The third method is needed to reproject the point from the coordinate space on the map (it's not relevant for the solution of my problem).

My code looks like this:

```
void onProjection(QGVMap* geoMap)
{
    QGVDrawItem::onProjection(geoMap);
    mProjPoint = geoMap->getProjection()->geoToProj(mPoint);
}

QPainterPath projShape() const
{
    QRectF _bounding = createGlyph().boundingRect();

    double _size = fmax(_bounding.height(), _bounding.width());

    QPainterPath _bounding_path;

    _bounding_path.addRect(0,0,_size,_size);

    _bounding_path.translate(mProjPoint.x(), mProjPoint.y());

    return _bounding_path;
}

// This function creates the path containing the airplane glyph
// along with its label
QPainterPath createGlyph() const
{
    QPainterPath _path;

    QPolygon _glyph = QPolygon();

    _glyph << QPoint(0,6) << QPoint(0,8) << QPoint(14,6) << QPoint(28,8) << QPoint(28,6) << QPoint(14,0);

     _path.addPolygon(_glyph);

     _path.setFillRule(Qt::FillRule::OddEvenFill);

    _path.addText(OFF_X_TEXT, OFF_Y_TEXT, mFont , QString::number(mId));

    QTransform _transform;

    _transform.rotate(mHeading);

    return _transform.map(_path);
}

// This function is the actual painting method
void drawGlyph(QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(mColor));
    painter->setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 1));

    QPainterPath _path = createGlyph();

    painter->translate(mProjPoint.x(), mProjPoint.y());

    painter->drawPath(_path);
}
```

Of course:

- `mProjPoint` is the position of the airplane,
- `mHeading` is the heading (the direction where the airplane is pointing),
- `mId` is a number identifying the airplane (will be displayed as a label *under* airplane glyph),
- `mColor` is the color assigned to the airplane.

The problem here is the mix of rotation and translation. Transformation: since the object is rotated, `projShape()` methods return a bounding rectangle that's not fully overlapping the object drawn on the map...

I also suspect that the *center* of the object is not correctly pointed on `mProjPoint`. I tried many times trying to translate the bounding rectangle to *center* the object without luck.

Another minor issue is the fillup of the font... the label under the airplane glyph is not solid, but it is filled with the same color of the airplane.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve the result I meant....

```
QPainterPath projShape() const
{
    QPainterPath _path;

        QRectF _glyph_bounds = _path.boundingRect();

        QPainterPath _textpath;

        _textpath.addText(0, 0, mFont, QString::number(mId));

        QRectF _text_bounds = _textpath.boundingRect();

        _textpath.translate(_glyph_bounds.width()/2-_text_bounds.width()/2, _glyph_bounds.height()+_text_bounds.height());

        _path.addPath(_textpath);

        QTransform _transform;

        _transform.translate(mProjPoint.x(),mProjPoint.y());

        _transform.rotate(360-mHeading);

        _transform.translate(-_path.boundingRect().width()/2, -_path.boundingRect().height()/2);

        return _transform.map(_path);
}

void projPaint(QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing, true);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing, true);

    painter->setBrush(QBrush(mColor));
    painter->setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 1));
    painter->setFont(mFont);

    QPainterPath _path = projShape();

    painter->drawPath(_path);
}
```

Unluckly I still suffer the *minor* issue with text fill mode:
I would like to have a solid black fill for the text instead of the `mColor` fill I use for the glyph/polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking, the general pattern for rotation is to scale about the origin first and then finish with your final translation.

The following is pseudocode, but it illustrates the need to shift your object's origin to (0, 0) prior to doing any rotation or scaling. After the rotate and scale are done, the object can be moved back from (0, 0) back to where it came from. From here, any post-translation step may be applied.

```
translate( -origin.x, -origin.y );
rotate( angle );
scale( scale.x, scale y);
translate(  origin.x,  origin.y );
translate(  translation.x, translation.y )
```

Comment: hi and thnx ... hope the last instruction should be a `translate()` instead a `scale()` or I really get lost somewhere....

Comment: @weirdgyn you are right, fixed.

Comment: as you can see the solution is pretty different but you addressed me the right way...